# MySQL join query with Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `EVENT` and `EVENT_INVITATION`.  I want to select all events where:

```
EVENT.creator_id = x
OR
EVENT_INVITATION.invitee_id = x
```

But I also need to return the total number of `EVENT_INVITATION` rows for each resultant `EVENT`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
SELECT count(*), EVENT.event_id
FROM EVENT, 
EVENT_INVITATION, 
(
  SELECT event_ID
  FROM EVENT
  WHERE creator_id = x
  UNION
  SELECT event_id
  FROM EVENT_INVITATION.
  WHERE invitee_id = x) temp
WHERE EVENT.event_ID = EVENT_INVITATION.event_ID
AND EVENT.event_ID = temp.event_ID
GROUP BY EVENT.event_id
```

I'd recommend doing a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) cause without your data structure and a sample set I have no way of testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all the events you care about, then count the associated invitations. Outer join in case there are no invitations.

```
WITH selectEvents AS (
    SELECT event_id
      FROM event
      WHERE creator_id = <x>
    UNION
    SELECT event_id
      FROM event_invitation
      WHERE invitee_id = <x>
)
SELECT s.event_id, COUNT(i.event_id) AS theCount
  FROM selectEvents s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN event_invitation i ON (i.event_id = s.event_id)
  GROUP BY s.event_id
```